# Massive differences in speed with virtually identical XQuery (exist-db) interogations

Tags: xquery, exist-db

I've been porting an SQL database over to exist over the last few weeks, and while I so far managed to get over all previous hindrances, I've now run into something for which neither the official documentation, searching online, nor common sense was able to help.

In short, I have a pretty big collection (about 90k entries, spread over 20 files), with most individual entries looking something like this (this is a massive simplification so I can get the point across):

```
<document>
 <document_id>Numerical Value</document_id>
 <page_id>Some other numerical value</page_id>
</document>
```

I then pass a value through php, lets call it `$val`
The strange part is that when I run the standard query

```
$p in collection("/db/folder_location")//documentset/document[xs:integer(document_id) eq $val]
```

No matter what value I pass, it returns all the results in a matter of seconds. If I slightly modify it, however, making it:

```
$p in collection("/db/folder_location")//documentset/document[xs:integer(page_id) eq $val]
```

It either takes over 30 seconds to return the values or simply stays locked in a running query and never returns anything. Of all the 30 queries I already converted, this is the only time I ran into this problem and could not find a workaround.

Comment: Strange indeed. Some troubleshooting/optimization questions to start us off: 1. Which version of eXist? 2. Have you defined any indexes on the collection? 3. Is it really necessary to cast the elements as `xs:integer` for your query to return accurate results?

Comment: Thanks for answering. 1. I'm using the latest version (4.0, XQuery 3.1). 2. I haven't defined any indexes yet. This is the first time I'm porting a database, so I thought I would first do the port and slight modifications and only index and optimize it afterwards. Maybe this wasn't the smartest choice. 3. I'm passing $val from php with get and XQuery picks it up as an integer most of the time, but it seems to think that page_id and document_id are strings if I don't cast them. I was going to either manually specify that they are integers or send $val as a string later on.

Comment: Great, thanks for this info. A couple more questions: 4. If you wrap the FLWOR expression in each query with the `count()` function, how many hits does the count return for each case? 5. How long do the count-wrapped queries take now? 6. How are you submitting your queries to eXist? Depending on the answers I should be able to offer an explanation and suggestion.

Comment: 4&5. The first one usually returns under 100 results (usually under 10) for most values in somewhere around 0.06 seconds. The second returns between 500 and 900 (upper half mostly) in about 1.6 seconds. If I do a composed query with a square complexity, the second takes about 30 seconds or never finishes, while the first still takes less than one second. 6. Not sure here/I just write my xqls in exide, and then access them as scripts with php.

Comment: Thanks for this info. It led me to provide the answer below regarding query performance. I'll be curious to hear if this helps. I didn't directly address your observation about the query "never finishing" - which may have more to do with the size of your collection and available memory. Indexes should help mitigate that, but if not, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To address the query performance problem, I would suggest some changes to your query and/or the addition of a range index on the `document_id` and `page_id` elements.

Your query casts all `document_id` and `page_id` elements as `xs:integer`. This is an inefficient operation given a large dataset. Consider (a) removing this type casting, (b) reversing it (cast `$val` as `xs:string`), or (c) adding a range index on these two elements, with `type="xs:integer"`. This latter option will let you remove the casting in your predicate (allowing you to change it to `document[document_id eq $val]` and `document[page_id eq $val]`), and the index should greatly speed the lookup.

To add a range index for your query, create a collection configuration document like this:

```
<collection xmlns="http://exist-db.org/collection-config/1.0">
    <index xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <range>
            <create qname="document_id" type="xs:integer"/>
            <create qname="page_id" type="xs:integer"/>
        </range>
    </index>
</collection>
```

If your data is in `/db/folder_location`, then store this document as `collection.xconf` in `/db/system/config/db/folder_location`. Then reindex your collection with `xmldb:reindex("/db/system/config/db/folder_location")`. As the documentation on range indexes states, with this index definition in place:

> indexes will be used automatically for general or value comparisons as well as string functions like `fn:contains`, `fn:starts-with`, `fn:ends-with`.

For more on range indexes in eXist, see https://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/newrangeindex.xml. For query optimization techniques, see https://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/tuning.xml. For indexes in general in eXist, see https://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/indexing.xml.

Comment: Yes, adding a range index did it. I really can't stress, for anybody who would run into this in the future, what a huge difference it made. The tunning tips were of course helpful, but just out of curiosity I kept the casts, added some random unneeded ones as well, and the difference was still unnoticeable (a few miliseconds at that). So thanks, this basically solved it. So, in case anybody also wants to make or port huge databases, do your indexes first, or at least in parallel with your code, don't leave them for later.

Comment: Good to hear! I'd say it's fine to begin work and prototype without indexes - until you start to experience discomfort from the speed of your query or are preparing for some prime-time, production deployment. At that point, it's definitely worth keeping indexes in mind. The query profiling tool available in the built-in Monitoring and Profiling tool ("monex") can give you a lot of insight into functions are taking the most time in your query and which expressions are benefiting from indexes and which are not. So there's no problem starting coding without indexes; just remember they're there.